# find a first match only and return remaining characters in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I am using regex to find a match in a string.

Input as "an"

variable as "banana"

need output as array ['b','a','n','a']

I tried below things :

https://regex101.com/r/k3bRid/1

**code**

```
var regex = '[^' + input + ']';
            regex = new RegExp(regex, 'gi')
            var reduceArr = variable.match(regex);
```

it should generate array with remaining characters excluding only first input match ..
Input can be single character or two character

**Example Tried:**

for input : "ta"

for variable : "talking"

it works fine

Comment: I don't quite understand. Your title asks for "remaining characters without duplicate", but `['b','a','n','a']` does have duplicate `a`s. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: sorry with duplicate of input ... Regex should match only first time... remaining characters should return as characters in array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the search string and replace the first find with an empty string. then split the string for getting only single characters.

```js
function getParts(input, string) {
    var regex = new RegExp(input, 'i')
    return string.replace(regex, '').split('');
}

console.log(getParts('an', 'banana'));
```

Comment: Thanks Nina .. Simple and great answer . Answers my ques every time :)

Answer (score 1):

This finds matches before and after the input string ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rPcCkD/1)):

```js
var input = 'an';
var variable = 'banana';

var regex = new RegExp('^(.*?)' + input + '(.*)$', 'i');
var reduceArr = (variable.match(regex) || []).slice(1).join('').split(''); // if matches where found, combine capture groups and split to characters

console.log(reduceArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var input = 'an';
            var variable = 'banana';
            var regex = variable.replace(input, '');;
            var arr=new Array(regex.split(''));
            console.log(arr);
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good one bro ... if you chained the lines, would be great

Answer (score 1):

No regexp needed. You may simply do as follows;

```js
var bazooka = (t,s) => s.replace(t,"").split("");

console.log(bazooka("an","banana"));
console.log(bazooka("harbur","berlingo"));
```